# Maximizing gameplay time in Spiral Knights

Tags: spiral-knights

With a nod towards [@mrrgl's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24640/is-it-possible-to-experience-all-content-in-spiral-knights-without-purchasing-cry), I have a question.

As a person not intending to spend real-world money on Spiral Knights (nor do I typically carry enough crowns to buy crystal energy), I find myself often running short on energy to experience dungeons past Moorcraft Manor.

Is it possible to somehow make it deeper than 10 dungeons on the free energy?  The only answer I can come up with is to leave SK running and let the energy replace itself over time while idling in game...but that would involve me having to leave my computer on quite a bit.

Comment: FYI, they have an idle timeout now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While, generally speaking, you are limited to ten floors of a dungeon per day, each dungeon is split into 3 separate Tiers. Each of these tiers starts at a different depth - 0, 8, and 18, So if you have Tier 2 Clearance, you can start at floor 8, and go all the way to floor 20 (no energy costs to access floors 13 and 18).

Likewise, if you start at floor 18 (tier 3 clearance), you can make it all the way to the core, Level 29, and still have 10 energy left over.

The one downside of this is that starting at Tier 2 or 3 costs Crowns (the in-game currency) -- 200 or 500 respectively. However, if you work your way through one gate sequentially - getting to floor 8 the first day, getting to floor 18 on the next, etc. you will avoid having to pay the cost in crowns.

Since gates have an 8-day cycle, this means you will be able to delve all the way to the Core 6 out of 8 days, avoiding the 'tax' for jumping directly into the deeper tiers. Alternatively, just jump directly into Tier 2 and Tier 3 without clearance; the Crown tax isn't *that* bad, and you will generally recoup your entry fee within the first floor or two.

Comment: Ignore the crown tax completely. 200 (or 500) crowns in this game is chump change, considering you can quite easily make 5000 crowns running through a tier with a full tank of mist energy (assuming you don't die horribly and need lots of revives.)

Comment: I agree, @Nicholas1024. See my last two sentences.

Comment: Followup then...how does one start at Tier 2?

Comment: @espais - make sure you've earned tier 2 clearance (all equipment is at least 2* + talk to the spiral warden)... actually, would you mind asking a new question for that? The simplest thing would be to simply link a picture to show you, and I can't do that in a comment.

Comment: @Raven: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31330/starting-at-a-different-tier-in-spiral-knights

Comment: [Energy is no more.](http://forums.spiralknights.com/en/node/84730) Turns out the devs were surprised that people don't risk weird stuff when they only have so many tries per day! _Who woulda thunk._

Comment: @badp Neat! Maybe I'll get back into this!

Answer (score 6):

As of the [July 30, 2013](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Release_Notes_2013-07-30) update, mist energy has been completely removed, and there is no energy cost to use elevators.

Thus, there really is no "ten floor maximum" restrictions now. You can explore the Clockworks to your heart's content!

Comment: Thank GOD they wised up and removed this. Was a total dealbreaker for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea is that you have to be generating enough crowns to buy crystal energy.  This may require you to make several runs with just your free energy for each run that you do using crystal energy (depending on the current market prices and how many crowns you can accumulate per run), and limiting your other crown expenditures as much as possible.  When you do use your crystal energy, it is especially important that you do so in a way that nets you a bunch of crowns, to get you started towards your next crystal energy purchase.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a continuous stream of energy for a day try one of these methods:

1) One method is to stockpile 2-star equips that are popular in the auction house. You could sell those to get enough crowns to pay off the materials you bought and still be able to buy a couple hundred crystal energy (depending on how much items you sold.)

2) Another is to do gates with bosses. Cash in your tokens earned from the bosses for equips. Sell, buy crystal energy with crowns, and repeat.