# Starting at a different Tier in Spiral Knights

Tags: spiral-knights

I have recently gained Tier 2 clearance. I have heard that it is possible to [simply pay a tax and start at Tier 2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31243/maximizing-gameplay-time-in-spiral-knights/31244#31244). I'd be interested in doing this, but I don't know how. Can somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the ADVENTURE BOARD, choosing to start at a different Tier is simple!

[image]

Here's the normal view. If you want to start at Tier 2 instead of Tier 1...

[image]

Simply click the "Tier 2" in the middle of the ADVENTURE BOARD. The tax, if applicable, will be shown below the energy cost.

Comment: Seriously...that's all there is to it?

Comment: I figured I had to go talk to somebody...thanks XD

Comment: @espais As long as you already have T2 clearance... it's *really* that simple.